# Cant write to shared memory. java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access Error

Tags: winapi, shared-memory, jna

I am trying to make shared memory and write to it, using JNA. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Here is my code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.PAGE_READWRITE;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class SharedMemoryTest
{
    private final MyKernel32 myKernel32;
    private Pointer SharedMemoryData;   
    private WinNT.HANDLE SharedMemoryHandle;

    public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32
    {
        MyKernel32 INSTANCE = (MyKernel32) Native.load("kernel32", MyKernel32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    }

    public SharedMemoryTest()
    {
        myKernel32 = MyKernel32.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        String SharedMemoryName = "SomeSharedMemory";
        int SharedMemorySize = 128;

        SharedMemoryHandle = myKernel32.CreateFileMapping((WinNT.HANDLE) INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, null, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SharedMemorySize, SharedMemoryName);

        if (SharedMemoryHandle == null) return;

        SharedMemoryData = myKernel32.MapViewOfFile(SharedMemoryHandle,
            PAGE_READWRITE,
            0, 0,
            SharedMemorySize);

        if (SharedMemoryData == null) return;

        System.out.println(SharedMemoryData.getByte(0));

        SharedMemoryData.setByte(0, (byte) 2);
    }
}
```

So, when I run test(), everything seems fine until the last line where i try to write to the memory with SharedMemoryData.setByte(0, (byte) 2);. This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access  
at com.sun.jna.Native.setByte(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.setByte(Pointer.java:993)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is, or have examples on how to setup shared memory like this?

Comment: I am new to programming and stackOverFlow. No one has answered and I am wondering, is this because it is a bad question, or is it just too niche to get answer's for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question is not about jna but about WinAPI.
The parameter PAGE_READWRITE is not valid parameter for MapViewOfFile, check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile
The valid parameters instead are FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FILE_MAP_READ, or other, starts with FILE_. Check the link for more detailed information.
The parameter PAGE_READWRITE instead is a valid parameter for CreateFileMapping.

Comment: omg that was it. I love you. I have spent so much time on this. Thankyou thankyou.                  For anyone who needs it, FileMapAllAccess = 0x001f,